# get List of routes via axios in Vue Webpack Cli

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, config, prerender

I'm using [prerender-spa-plugin](https://github.com/chrisvfritz/prerender-spa-plugin) in my Vue Webpack Cli project. Like from the documentation i'm registering the Plugin in webpack.prod.conf.js like this

```
...
plugins: [
  ...
  new PrerenderSpaPlugin(
    path.join(__dirname, '../dist'),
    ['/', '/about', '/contact'],
    {
      captureAfterTime: 5000
    }
  )
]
```

I'm wondering if it would be possible to get the list of routes array via an axios call.
I tried the following without success:

```
var routes = axios.get('http://myapi.com/api').then(function (response) {
  return response.map(function (response) {
    return '/base/' + response.slug
  })
})

plugins: [
  ...
  new PrerenderSpaPlugin(
    path.join(__dirname, '../dist'),
    routes,
    {
      captureAfterTime: 5000
    }
  )
]
```

Since my Javascript knowledge is poor I'm not able to solve this. Thankfull for any hints.

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This currently won't work (or at least work reliably) because Webpack assumes your configuration is synchronous by default. To get around this is to use Webpack's support for [asynchronous configuration](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/2697) and return a promise that is resolved after your route request.

If you are in an environment that supports `async/await` (node 8+) then it's as simple as exporting an `async` function. Otherwise, return a `new Promise`:

```
// webpack.conf.js
module.exports = async function () {
  const response = await axios.get('http://myapi.com/api')
  const routes = response.map((response) => {
    return '/base/' + response.slug
  })

  return {
    plugins: [
      // ...
      new PrerenderSpaPlugin(
        path.join(__dirname, '../dist'),
        routes,
        {
          captureAfterTime: 5000
        }
      )
    ]
  }
}
```

If that isn't an option, you can always have a task that makes this request, writes it to a `json` file, and then `require('./route-response.json')` in your config.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement - to get the list of routes from my API. I ended up creating a prebuild script - **prebuild.js**

```
const fs = require('fs')
const axios = require('axios')

// Fetch data from API
axios.get('http://myapi.com/api.php')
  .then(function(response) {
    const data = response.data
    try {
      // Save the route list to local file
      fs.writeFileSync('./route-response.js', data)
    } catch(err) {
      console.log(err)
    }
  })
  .catch(function(err) {
    console.log(err)
  })
```

My API sends the data of the **route-response.js** file, ready to be directly saved and consumed by npm. You could handle this formatting in Node instead. Sample format:

```
module.exports = {
  theList: [
    '/',
    '/about',
    '/contact',
    '/login',
    '/register'
  ]
}
```

The above file is fetched in **webpack.prod.conf.js** as below:

```
...
const routeList = require('./route-response.js')
...
const webpackConfig = merge(baseWebpackConfig, {
  ...
  plugins: [
    ...
    new PrerenderSPAPlugin({
      staticDir: path.resolve(__dirname, '../dist'),
      routes: routeList.theList,
      renderer: new PuppeteerRenderer()
    })
    ...
  ]
  ...
})
```

and finally, add the prebuild script to the **package.json**

- *prebuild:* runs before the build step.
- *postbuild:* runs after the build step.

Here's a sample

```
...
"scripts": {
  "dev": "node build/dev-server.js",
  "prebuild": "node build/prebuild.js",
  "build": "node build/build.js"
},
"dependencies": {
...
```

This way, I only have to run **npm run build**